# How to add custom js script on the <head> tag in magento2

Tags: header, script, google-tag-manager

Hi here am trying to add a js script to the `<head>` tag,

methods used

1. Content => Design => Configuration, Now click on the edit link of the current theme and Go to the HTML Head tab and inside scripts and style sheets text-area you can enter your custom script.
2. create an XML file on theme location:
   `app/design/frontend/packagename/themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

Created a template file on following location:
`app/design/frontend/packagename/themename/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header/head_tags.phtml`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log("custom head!");
</script>
<script defer>(function (w, d, s, l, i) {
      w[l] = w[l] || []; w[l].push({
        'gtm.start':
          new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js'
      }); var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : ''; j.async = true; j.src =
          'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl; f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
    })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-NMWGPRJ');</script>
  <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

But it's not getting under Header, it's coming on Body.

[image]

where I'm doing wrong. can I get some help? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**
To add your Scripts and Style Sheets via admin panel:

1. Go to CONTENT -> Design -> Configuration
2. Click on the Edit link of your current theme.
3. Under 'Other Settings'  expand the `HTML Head` section.
4. Place your script under the 'Scripts and Style Sheets' input box.
5. Click on the 'Save Configuration' button.

**Method 2:**
To add your Scripts and Style Sheets via layout and template file in theme:

1. Go to location: `app/design/frontend/vendor/yourtheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/head.phtml`
2. Add your script code in `head.phtml` file.
3. Save your file changes.

Clear your Magento store cache by running the below command after implementing the above changes.

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Now check your script is placed under the `<head>` & `</head>` tags

Comment: hi @Ubed Shaikh Thank you for the response. Here I have used both methods. and added my script in

`app/design/frontend/vendor/yourtheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/head.phtml` and 
`app/design/frontend/vendor/yourtheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml`
but still script is running inside `<body>`.

Comment: @PraveenNegimani Please use one method at a time. I recommend you for using **Method 1** which is a default in Magento.

Comment: I have the same problem. With method 1, which seems to be recommended, <head> starts on line 3. My script is at line 65... below many other scripts and fonts.

The script is a cookie tool, which should load before all other stuff to function well. But I can't seem to get it to the top of the head.

As for method 2:
I searched for head.phtml in my whole magento 2 installation and found no file with that name (find /var/www/html/magento2 -type f -name "head.phtml")
Is this normal and if I create it, it will work? In that case, do I only put my script tag in head.phtml and nothing more?